# How do I create the attached text annotation component where I can highlight and name a block of text in a text display box?

Tags: user-interface, text, annotations, web-component

I was looking to use the following component:
[Adding information on text blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeRHs.png)

I am unable to find the component that can build this. I would be super greatful if you could share how this could be done within python libraries like streamlit or some other such python based frontend libraries.

Thank you.

I did a lot of searches online but I don't know the technical name of the component and therefore I cannot find a solution online. I also tried a reverse image search on Google but can't find the name of the component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use this inside of streamlit, I would recommend using the `st-annotated-text` library. It has the exact functionality as the image you shared. You can find additional information about the library on its GitHub page: https://github.com/tvst/st-annotated-text

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. The component you linked to only displays the text. It isn't an input component. I was wondering there was a way to create a similar input functionality.